# If input is NULL, return -1

Tags: c++, function, pointers, input, null

Code works fine except I need to add this constraint.
"If input is NULL, return -1".

Im just wondering how I can do this. Everytime I put NULL in for s, it crashes.

Side Note: If you need to know, this converts the excel titles to numbers like A = 1, Z = 26, AA = 27, AB = 28, etc.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CIS14
{
public:
int convertExcelTitleToNumber(string* s)
{

    string str = *s;

    int num = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        num = num * 26 + str[i] - 64;
    }
    return num;
}
};
int main()
{
CIS14 cis14;
string s = "AA";
cout << cis14.convertExcelTitleToNumber(&s) << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why are you using a pointer at all? Is your function meant to perform something if input is `nullptr`? Just take a reference and force callers to pass a `std::string`.

Comment: @Tas, your advice is excellent. Unfortunately, `CIS14` smacks of a classwork assignment so this is probably a requirement, by some educator with little real-world experience, or is what I like to call a `C+` programmer, one who never fully embraced the transition from `C` to `C++` :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Everytime I put `NULL` in for `s`, it crashes.

That doesn't surprise me at all, dereferencing a null pointer (with `string str = *s` in your case) is undefined behaviour.

To prevent this when passing a null string pointer:

```
cout << cis14.convertExcelTitleToNumber(nullptr) << endl;
```

you need something like this as the *first* thing in your function, *before* trying to dereference `s`:

```
if (s == nullptr)
    return -1
```

Feel free to use `NULL` instead of `nullptr` if you're stuck in the dark ages :-)